# Include Div tag in jsp

Tags: html, jsp

```
<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){

     $(function() {
        $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate:1,dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' });
     });

     // on changing date initilize the countdown again
     $("#datepicker").change(function(){
        init($(this).val());
     })

     function init(dt){
        $('#clock').countdown(dt).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
            var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''

              +'<span>%-d</span> day%!d '
              ));
        });
     }

     //initilize counter on load with some default date
     init("2016/11/25");
  });</script>



    <td><strong>
    <%out.print("<div id=\"clock\">"+rs.getString(8)+"</div>"); %>
    </strong></td>
```

I want to print the div content in jsp tag.What i should do to display div in jsp's output.Please help me out.I would appreciate your good solutions.

Comment: despite of the single line `<%out.print(...);%>` i don't know why the other code is in the question. Please format it to make the question more readable and helpful for others

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to use:

```
<%out.print("<div id=\"clock\">"+rs.getString(8)+"</div>"); %>
```

You can simple use:

```
<div id="clock"><%=rs.getString(8)%></div>
```

In a JSP file you can use any html tag directly.

Comment: No need of <%out.print%> ah?

Comment: If i use only <div id="clock"><%=rs.getString(8)%></div> it won't works.

Comment: try first with `<div id="clock">Some Text for Testing</div>`. Does it work? if so then the issue is in  `<%=rs.getString(8)%>`. Is the rs defined?

Comment: if i use individually both codes are working fine.But when i execute both at a time i will not get any output!!