# DIV tag inside JSP expression

Tags: html, jsp

```html
<html>
  <head>
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function(){

         $(function() {
            $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ minDate:1,dateFormat: 'yy/mm/dd' });
         });

         // on changing date initilize the countdown again
         $("#datepicker").change(function(){
            init($(this).val());
         })

         function init(dt){
            $('#clock').countdown(dt).on('update.countdown', function(event) {
                var $this = $(this).html(event.strftime(''
                  
                  +'<span>%-d</span> day%!d '
                  ));
            });
         }

         //initilize counter on load with some default date
         init("2016/12/25");

      });
</script>
    </head>
  <body>
    <table >
 <thead>

<tr>
<th width="50">
S.NO
</th>
<th>
SchoolId
</th>
<th>
RegistrationDate
</th>
<th>
SchoolName
</th>
<th>
SchoolAddress
</th>
<th>
SchoolPin
</th>
<th>
SchoolPassword
</th>
<th>
Validity
</th>
<th>
Export To Excel
</th>

</tr>
 </thead>
  <tbody>
    
    <%

    while(rs.next())
    {
     %>
     <tr align="center">
     
     <td><strong>
     <%out.print(rs.getString(1)); %>
     </strong></td>
     
     <td><strong>
     <%out.print(rs.getString(2)); %>
     </strong></td>
          
     <td><strong>
     <%out.print(rs.getString(3)); %>
     </strong></td>
     
     <td><strong>
     <%out.print(rs.getString(4)); %>
     </strong></td>
     
     <td><strong>
     <%out.print(rs.getString(5)); %>
     </strong></td>
     
     <td><strong>
     <%out.print(rs.getString(6)); %>
     </strong></td>
     
     <td><strong>
     <%out.print(rs.getString(7)); %>
     </strong></td>
         
     <td><strong><div id="clock">
      <%out.print(rs.getString(8));%>
     </div></strong></td>
         
     <td><strong>
    <a href="export.jsp?school=<%=(rs.getString(2))%>" class="btn btn-success btn-sm">
                   Export
                 </a>
     </strong></td>
     
        
     </tr>
     
   
     <%
    }
}
catch(Exception e)
{
 System.out.println(e);
}
%>
</tbody>
 </table>
    </body>
    </html>
```

I want to display remaining days in validity column,to do so i just inserted
div tag in jsp expression as shown( <%out.print(rs.getString(8));%> ). i'm not getting the output in table data.Please help me out to get remaining days in validity column.I would appreciate your good answers.

Comment: I think you might have to add jquery library..

Comment: I tried this one also  `<%out.print("<div id=\"clock\">"+rs.getString(8)+"</div>");%>` but no output!!

Comment: is jquery library added  like this for eg. here 1.10 : <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.js"></script>

Comment: Yeah already included.

Comment: i see you post the same question again, but with more code. The original question (from other account with your name) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/40779483/include-div-tag-in-jsp

Comment: But i still didn't get the ans for the same! Can anybody Please Help Me Out!!!!Thanx.